# Doxygen uses Templates instead of Generics in C# generated documentation

Tags: c#, generics, doxygen

I have a generic Type in my source code that I have some documentation around. I am then running doxygen against the source code, while having the `Optmize for Java or C# output` enabled, so that I can have documentation for my project. The XML commenting in one of my files looks like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// <para>
/// The Engine Timer allows for starting a timer that will execute a callback at a given interval.
/// </para>
/// <para>
/// The timer may fire:
///  - infinitely at the given interval
///  - fire once
///  - fire _n_ number of times.
/// </para>
/// <para>
/// The Engine Timer will stop its self when it is disposed of.
/// </para>
/// <para>
/// The Timer requires you to provide it an instance that will have an operation performed against it.
/// The callback will be given the generic instance at each interval fired.
/// </para>
/// <para>
/// In the following example, the timer is given an instance of an IPlayer. 
/// It starts the timer off with a 30 second delay before firing the callback for the first time.
/// It tells the timer to fire every 60 seconds with 0 as the number of times to fire. When 0 is provided, it will run infinitely.
/// Lastly, it is given a callback, which will save the player every 60 seconds.
/// @code
/// var timer = new EngineTimer<IPlayer>(new DefaultPlayer());
/// timer.StartAsync(30000, 6000, 0, (player, timer) => player.Save());
/// @endcode
/// </para>
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type that will be provided when the timer callback is invoked.</typeparam>
public sealed class EngineTimer<T> : CancellationTokenSource, IDisposable
{
}
```

However the documentation that gets generated says that `T` in this scenario is a `Template Parameter`, which I believe to be a C++ 11 thing(?).

[image]

Is there a way for me to rename that within the wizard, so that it says `Generic Type Parameter` as from the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zk36dx2.aspx)?

I also noticed that when the documentation includes `Engine` or other namespace names, that it adds a hyperlink to the namespace documentation page. Is there any markup I can use to tell Doxygen to ignore `Engine` in certain scenarios, such as in the XML above, but not in all XML?

I looked through the documentation but came up empty on both of these questions.

Thanks

Comment: The correct term would be "type parameter", I believe.

Comment: Close, Microsoft's documentation shows it as a [Generic Type Parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zk36dx2.aspx). I've updated my OP accordingly.

Comment: In the heading of the page I see: EngineTimer< T > Class Template Reference, is this correct?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. The class definition is `EngineTimer<T> with xml documentation for `<T>` specified with `<typeparam>` tags, for indicating it is a Type parameter

Comment: In the heading of the HTML page above the Detailed section we first get an inheritance diagram and above this I see the text mentioned before.